# read.table as it is

Tags: r, import

I'm trying to read data from csv file, but instead of e.g. 001000 I get 1000 in my data.
I've tried to set `as.is=!stringsAsFactors`, but got the following error message:

```
 error: object stringsAsFactors not found.
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found workaround: add `colClasses` description

```
data_raw <- read.table("data",
                     colClasses=c("character","character","character"),
                     sep="\t",
                     quote="\"")
```

How to convert character to vector:

It's easier to use separators in data, because finally you'll get character and to convert it to e.g. vector you should do smth like:

```
m <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit("0,1,1,1,0",split=",")))
m
[1] 0 1 1 1 0
```

or

```
m<-as.integer(scan(textConnection("0,1,1,1,0"),sep=","))
```